# Migration from PARSE mobile backend to Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created a social media app using Parse backend. I don't have any user at this point but I am anticipating to get lots of users in the future. I have several problems with Parse:

1- Parse limits API calls and my app needs to work on million users' phone and 600 call / sec is not enough to support millions of users
2- Auto Scalability is a critical requirement for social media and Parse doesn't provide it
3-There is no tech support from Parse team and they are not even available to solve our issues. I don't know why they do not provide paid consulting services to help their customers

So I decided to move the backend to Google App engine

**My Questions:**

*1- Is there any way to solve the three issues mentioned above Using Parse so that I stay on Parse without migration to another backend? and How?
2- If the answer is No, what's the best mobile backend to accommodate my requirements?
3- what are the challenges moving from Parse to Google App Engine (GAE)
4- Parse keeps everything in MangoDb - what happens if I create another MangoDb on GAE and replicate the same DB schema? how about queries and cloud code that we have written on MangoDb and Parse? do we need to rewrite them again?*

I would truly appreciate it if you guys would give me some advise - I am ready to hire someone who has done this kind of work in the past and has a good experience on Parse.

Thank you
Ben

Comment: Too many questions! SO is for answering one question at a time. Break this down to single questions, and look at the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what makes a good question.